# Value of select option

Tags: php, html, forms

Hi im trying to get a value from a select option but the value sent is always 1 i dont know why here is the code:

```
<form id="landingform"  method="POST" action="form/process.php">
<input id="nme" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"  />
<input id="mail" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email"  />
<input name="address" type="text" placeholder="Address"  />
<select name="state">
  <option value="Alabama" selected="selected">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
  <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
  <option value="California">California </option>
  <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
  <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut </option>
  <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
  <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
  <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
  <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
  <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
  <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
  <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
  <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
  <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
  <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
  <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
  <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
  <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
  <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
  <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
  <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
  <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
  <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
  <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
  <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
  <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
  <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
  <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
  <option value="New York">New York</option>
  <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
  <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
  <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
  <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
  <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
  <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
  <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
  <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
  <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
  <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
  <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
  <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
  <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
  <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
  <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
  <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
  <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<input name="zipcode" type="text" placeholder="Zipcode" />
<input id="msg" name="coment" type="text" placeholder="Comments..." style="height:50px;"/>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="" onclick="return validateForm()"/>
</form>
```

the process.php:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$zipcode = $_POST["zipcode"];
$state   = isset($_POST["state"]);
$coment = $_POST["coment"];

/* This takes the information and lines it up the way you want it to be sent in the email. */

$subject = ' Contact From '.$name; // Subject for the email
        $body = "Name: $name <br />";
        $body .= "Email: $email <br />";
        $body .= "Address: $address <br />";
        $body .= "State: $state <br />";
        $body .= "Zipcode: $zipcode <br />";
        $body .= "Msg: $coment <br />";
        $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'  . "<br />";
        $sucess = mail($site_owners_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
$url = '../thank-you.html';
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
?>
```

i get all the other values just fine but state always is value 1 in the mail why is this? is like a boolean value? thanks

Comment: because you're assigning `isset($_POST['state'])` which will return a boolean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$state   = isset($_POST["state"]);
```

will return a boolean. This is the reason why you are getting 1.

You should do it this way:

```
 $state   = $_POST["state"];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have

```
$state = isset($_POST["state"]);
```

change it to

```
$state = $_POST["state"];
```

The first one is returning a boolean because it checks if that variable **is set** or not.

Answer (score 0):

In state you put isset($_POST["state"])
This is a boolean
The 1 you see means true
You have to write :

```
$state   = $_POST["state"];
```